# jQuery serialize selects and inputs in array how to pick them up in PHP loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, serialization

I'm trying to create a function where a user should select an option from a `<select>` and add a date to the value selected (inside `<input type='text'>` on the same row). Then when the fields have been inputted send as an array to a `PHP` file and inserted to a database.

I'm creating the `<select>`, and `<input type='text'>` dynamically on the same row in a table.

Selects look something like this: `<input type='select' class='add_absence_type'>`
Input fields: `<input type='text' class='add_absence_date'>`

The script I'm working on looks like this at the moment:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
function serealizeSelects (select)
    {
        var array = [];
        select.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
        return array;
    }
function serealizeInputs (input)
    {
        var array = [];
        input.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
        return array;
    }
    var student_id = $('#student_id').val();
    var add_absence_type = serealizeSelects($('.add_absence_type'));
    var add_absence_date = serealizeInputs($('.add_absence_date'));

    $.post('../updateAbsence.php', {

    student_id: student_id,
    add_absence_type: add_absence_type,
    add_absence_date: add_absence_date

    }, function(data) {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

The `$_POST` data looks like this:

```
student_id  1
add_absence_date[]  2012-11-13
add_absence_date[]  2012-11-14
add_absence_type[]  1
add_absence_type[]  2
```

What do I need to do to create a PHP loop that creates `mysql_query`'s like this? See below:

`"INSERT INTO my_table (student_id, absence_type_id, absence_date) VALUES ('1', '1', '2012-11-13')"`

`"INSERT INTO my_table (student_id, absence_type_id, absence_date) VALUES ('1', '2', '2012-11-14')"`

Comment: `foreach($_POST['add_absence_date'] as $key=>$value){..}` you can use this way and build query into foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?php
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'] ;
$absence_date_arr = $_POST['add_absence_date'] ;
$absence_type = $_POST['add_absence_type'] ;

foreach($absence_date_arr as $key=> $absence_date){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table (student_id, absence_type_id, absence_date) VALUES ('".$student_id."', '".$absence_type[$key]."', '".$absence_date."')");  
}
?>
```